# Don't know why MySQL is not creating table with primary key constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, primary-key, constraint, table

I can't understand why MySQL showing this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CONSTRAINT (uname_pk) PRIMARY KEY, pwd Varchar(50), fname
>   Varchar(50), lname ' at line 1

And this is the query:

```
create table uinfo_master(uname Varchar(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT (uname_pk) PRIMARY KEY,
pwd Varchar(50),
fname Varchar(50),
lname Varchar(50),
email Varchar(50),
phno Varchar(50),
address Varchar(200),
city Varchar(50),
state Varchar(50),
pin Varchar(50),
country Varchar(50));
```

What is wrong with my query, kindly show my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax, with minimal changes to your style:

```
create table uinfo_master(
uname Varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT uname_pk PRIMARY KEY (uname),
pwd Varchar(50),
fname Varchar(50),
lname Varchar(50),
email Varchar(50),
phno Varchar(50),
address Varchar(200),
city Varchar(50),
state Varchar(50),
pin Varchar(50),
country Varchar(50));
```

You cannot use the `CONSTRAINT` syntax for the PK on the same line as the column definition.

See the [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) syntax:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    { LIKE old_tbl_name | (LIKE old_tbl_name) }

create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

Defining the column itself is done on the `col_name column_definition` version of the syntax. The `|` that follows that stands for OR in the documentation, meaning an alternate CREATE TABLE (comma separated) "line" can use the syntax that starts with `CONSTRAINT`, which optionally includes a "symbol" (that's what brackets mean: optional), then `PRIMARY KEY`, optionally an `index_type`, and then the column itself, in parentheses.

From the look of it, you tried to do all that on one line, which was where your problem was. You *can* declare a column to be a PRIMARY KEY on the line the column is defined, but you cannot use the CONSTRAINT syntax to do so.

Comment: Declaring a field `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY` is pointless - by definition if a field is a `PRIMARY KEY` (on its own), it cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Thank you for your detailed answer, but I came to know about this syntax from this site https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html see the query given on the site `-- column-level primary key constraint named OUT_TRAY_PK:
CREATE TABLE SAMP.OUT_TRAY
 (
 SENT TIMESTAMP,
 DESTINATION CHAR(8),
 SUBJECT CHAR(64) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT OUT_TRAY_PK PRIMARY KEY,
 NOTE_TEXT VARCHAR(3000) 
   );`

Comment: That is Oracle syntax, not MySQL.  Stick with stuff at dev.mysql.com .

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for clearing this confusion.